# issue with oracle output parameters in c#

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, output-parameter

I am so mad at oracle. I have been battling to get two values (output paramaters) from oracle database. I need to get two values (o_unallocated_ledgercode and o_allocated_ledgercode) based on paymentType and vendor.

What issue is: these values remain null in C#. I cannot get these values from database. what may be wrong? please look at my c# codes. i need someone's different perspective. I may have missed something. Please give me code example. Thanks!

**Oracle package:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package body BANKIMPORTS.pkg_vendor_config as

PROCEDURE get_ledger_codes (i_vendor in varchar2,
                            i_payment_type in varchar2,
                            o_allocated_ledgercode out varchar2,
                            o_unallocated_ledgercode out varchar2) is
BEGIN
  IF UPPER (i_payment_type) = 'SUBS' THEN
    SELECT CV.CONFIGVALUE
      INTO o_unallocated_ledgercode
      FROM VENDOR v
      JOIN VENDOR_CONFIG_ITEM_VALUE CV ON v.Id = CV.Vendor_Id
      JOIN CONFIG_ITEMS c ON CV.Config_Item_Id = c.Config_Item_Id
      WHERE C.ITEMNAME = 'Subs_Unallocated_LederCode'
        AND V.DESCRIPTION = i_vendor;

    SELECT CV.CONFIGVALUE
      INTO o_allocated_ledgercode
      FROM VENDOR v
      JOIN VENDOR_CONFIG_ITEM_VALUE CV ON v.Id = CV.Vendor_Id
      JOIN CONFIG_ITEMS c ON CV.Config_Item_Id = c.Config_Item_Id
      WHERE C.ITEMNAME = 'Subs_Payment_LedgerCode'
        AND V.DESCRIPTION = i_vendor;
  ELSIF UPPER (i_payment_type) = 'GOTV'
    ........same select statement as above
```

**C# codes:**

```
using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
  {
  try
    {
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "pkg_vendor_config.get_ledger_codes";
    command.AddParameter("i_vendor", DbType.String, vendor, ParameterDirection.Input);
    command.AddParameter("i_payment_type", DbType.String, paymentType, ParameterDirection.Input);

    command.AddParameter("o_unallocated_ledgercode", DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Output);
    command.AddParameter("o_allocated_ledgercode", DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Output);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    var unallocated = (String)command.Parameters["o_unallocated_ledgercode"].Value;
    var allocated = (String)command.Parameters["o_allocated_ledgercode"].Value;
```

Comment: Did you mean to put `o_unallocated_ledgercode` ahead of `o_allocated_ledgercode` in your `C#` code? In your Oracle Procedure, the order is reversed. Also, do you get any errors or messages from your Output window?

Comment: no i need to fetch two values (o_unallocated_ledgercode and o_allocated_ledgercode) in C# from procedure. What do "the order is reversed" mean?

Comment: You might want to add a check after your procedure has been invoked to be sure that the returned SQLCODE value is zero.  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr;** I think you just need to set the parameters' Size properties.

According to docs.oracle.com's [page on the OracleParameter class object](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15296_01/doc.111/e15167/OracleParameterClass.htm#i1012269), when we click on the Size property we see that the default maximum size for a parameter type is 0!

When I set all of your Varchar2 parameters I don't get the null values anymore. I had set them to 50 but that will be dependent on your VENDOR_CONFIG_ITEM_VALUE.CONFIGVALUE property's limits are set to.

**C# code:**

```
using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();

    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "pkg_vendor_config.get_ledger_codes";

    OracleParameter[] yourParams = new[] 
    { 
        new OracleParameter("i_vendor", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "subs", ParameterDirection.Input), 
        new OracleParameter("i_payment_type", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "cold hard cash", ParameterDirection.Input),
        new OracleParameter("o_allocated_ledgercode", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output), 
        new OracleParameter("o_unallocated_ledgercode", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output)
    };

    foreach(var param in yourParams)
    {
         param.Size = 50;
    }

    command.Parameters.AddRange (yourParams);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    var unallocated = (String)command.Parameters["o_unallocated_ledgercode"].Value.ToString();
    var allocated = (String)command.Parameters["o_allocated_ledgercode"].Value.ToString();

    connection.Close();
}
```

**Oracle package:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure pkg_vendor_config.get_ledger_codes(i_vendor in varchar2,
                                i_payment_type in varchar2,
                                o_allocated_ledgercode out varchar2,
                                o_unallocated_ledgercode out varchar2) is
BEGIN
        SELECT 'Another value'
        INTO o_unallocated_ledgercode
        FROM dual;

        SELECT 'Some value'
        INTO o_allocated_ledgercode
        FROM dual;

    /* I'll assume this all behaved for you

    IF UPPER (i_payment_type) = 'SUBS' THEN
    SELECT CV.CONFIGVALUE
      INTO o_unallocated_ledgercode
      FROM VENDOR v
      JOIN VENDOR_CONFIG_ITEM_VALUE CV ON v.Id = CV.Vendor_Id
      JOIN CONFIG_ITEMS c ON CV.Config_Item_Id = c.Config_Item_Id
      WHERE C.ITEMNAME = 'Subs_Unallocated_LederCode'
        AND V.DESCRIPTION = i_vendor;

    SELECT CV.CONFIGVALUE
      INTO o_allocated_ledgercode
      FROM VENDOR v
      JOIN VENDOR_CONFIG_ITEM_VALUE CV ON v.Id = CV.Vendor_Id
      JOIN CONFIG_ITEMS c ON CV.Config_Item_Id = c.Config_Item_Id
      WHERE C.ITEMNAME = 'Subs_Payment_LedgerCode'
        AND V.DESCRIPTION = i_vendor;
  ELSIF UPPER (i_payment_type) = 'GOTV'
    ........same select statement as above
 */

end;
```

*Disclaimer:*

*I can't seem recreate your C# setup exactly; may have all been made obsolete since it's been nearly 6 years. But this is confirmed working*

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting up the values of the variables. If you want to return something use function.

```
FUNCTION get_ledger_codes
( 
  i_vendor in varchar2
, i_payment_type in varchar2
) RETURN VARCHAR2
is
    o_allocated_ledgercode   varchar2(100);
    o_unallocated_ledgercode varchar2(100);
BEGIN
    IF UPPER (i_payment_type) = 'SUBS'  THEN
        SELECT CV.CONFIGVALUE
        INTO o_unallocated_ledgercode
        FROM VENDOR v
             JOIN VENDOR_CONFIG_ITEM_VALUE CV ON v.Id = CV.Vendor_Id
             JOIN CONFIG_ITEMS c ON CV.Config_Item_Id = c.Config_Item_Id
        WHERE     C.ITEMNAME = 'Subs_Unallocated_LederCode'
             AND V.DESCRIPTION = i_vendor;

        SELECT CV.CONFIGVALUE
        INTO o_allocated_ledgercode
        FROM VENDOR v
             JOIN VENDOR_CONFIG_ITEM_VALUE CV ON v.Id = CV.Vendor_Id
             JOIN CONFIG_ITEMS c ON CV.Config_Item_Id = c.Config_Item_Id
        WHERE     C.ITEMNAME = 'Subs_Payment_LedgerCode'
             AND V.DESCRIPTION = i_vendor;

    ELSIF UPPER (i_payment_type) = 'GOTV'
        ........same select statement as above

    RETURN o_allocated_ledgercode || ',' || o_unallocated_ledgercode;
END;
```

Comment: RETURN o_allocated_ledgercode || ',' || o_unallocated_ledgercode; should be at the end of if statement? do you think my c# codes are correct?

Comment: these values still remains null in c# after i changed as you advised. please review my c# codes. i would appreciate it so much thanks

Comment: I have not done C# for a while. The only thing that looks new is (String)command.Parameters can it be replaced with: command.Parameters[i].ToString()?